# convert NSDateComponents to NSDate

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How can I convert `NSDateComponents` to `NSDate()`?

```
let dateFormatter: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
dateFormatter.calendar   = NSCalendar(identifier: NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian)

var dateii = NSDate(toDate)// toDate from NSDateComponents  error 1
let dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(toDate) //error 2
```

Error 1:

> Argument labels '(_:)' do not match any available overloads

Error 2:

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSDateComponents' to expected argument type 'NSDate'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `NSData` instead of `NSDate`. A typo.

As for your string, the date formatter transforms a **date** into a string, not date components. You have to first make a date out of the components.

```
let dateToDisplay = calendar.dateFromComponents(components)!
```

*These errors would not have occurred if you had read the documentation or tried to understand relevant sample code.*